# MySQL socket disappeared

Tags: mysql

I was running a Python script that lasted a few hours and executed insert statements. All locally on Debian. When I came back later to check on the script's status, I was no longer able to log into MySQL.

I had had a command line session going, and this was the message:

[image: command line session]

A similar message appears when I try to log in or run diagnostic functions like mysqldump. It appears that the socket just got up and walked away. The script and database had been running swimmingly several times before this. The only thing that changed was that I tweaked the script to do a heavier load (processing CSV files), so all can figure is that I ran out of memory and something crashed while I was away.

Trying to restart:

```
root@debian:/home/user# /etc/init.d/mysql stop
[ ok ] Stopping mysql (via systemctl): mysql.service.
root@debian:/home/user# /etc/init.d/mysql start
[....] Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.serviceJob for mysql.service failed. See 'systemctl status mysql.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
 failed!
```

systemctl status mysql.service:

```
root@debian:/home/user# systemctl status mysql.service
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled)
   Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-02-15 19:26:44 JST; 12s ago
  Process: 3324 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=2)
  Process: 3317 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3324 (code=exited, status=2);         : 3326 (mysql-systemd-s)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─control
             ├─3326 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
             └─3373 sleep 1

Feb 15 19:26:44 debian systemd[1]: mysql.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Feb 15 19:26:44 debian systemd[1]: Stopping MySQL Community Server...
Feb 15 19:26:44 debian systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Feb 15 19:26:46 debian systemd[1]: mysql.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
```

journalctl -xn:

```
Feb 15 19:26:44 debian systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Feb 15 19:26:44 debian systemd[1]: Unit mysql.service entered failed state.
Feb 15 19:26:44 debian systemd[1]: mysql.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Feb 15 19:26:44 debian systemd[1]: Stopping MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has begun shutting down.
Feb 15 19:26:44 debian systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun with start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
Feb 15 19:26:46 debian systemd[1]: mysql.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
```

Comment: Do you have `apparmor` running? I've seen reports of this error when apparmor was blocking MySQL from starting. Further, I'd recommend checking the MySQL error log. It's either in your datadir or in /var/log.

Comment: @BillKarwin Thank you for the idea. I installed user controls for apparmor [per the instructions](https://wiki.debian.org/AppArmor/HowToUse) and played around with the settings, but nothing came of it. I resolved the issue by adding the line `innodb_force_recovery = 4` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14837653/cannot-start-mysql).

Comment: You know you shouldn't leave that setting on permanently, right? It blocks InnoDB from doing some necessary background cleanup. If you set that option, you should just use it while you dump all your data with `mysqldump` to get a full backup. Then restore the dump to a new installation of MySQL. The purpose is to create new tablespaces, because apparently your current tablespaces have gotten corrupted. Read more here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html